# Passing variables to java process

Tags: java, windows, curl, process, cmd

I am not sure if this is possible but does anyone know if it possible to pass a variable to a java process?

My code is:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c *curl command* -o "file.png");
```

And I want to do look something like:

```
int X = 0;

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c *curl command* -o "fileX.png");

X++;
```

This way I can have output like:

```
file0.png

file1.png

file2.png
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take effort in writing the question as other people are trying to help you ... refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you mean a loop like `for (int i = 0;i<xxxx;++i) String filename = "File"+i+".png";?`

Comment: Yes! String concatenation. I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially building a string.

```
for (int x=0;x<MAX;x++){
    String command = "cmd /c curl command -o \"file" + x + ".png\"";
    // use it!
}
```